# Qcube/Qcodo dynamic input fields

Tags: dynamic, input, field, qcodo

Does anybody have an example how can I add dynamically input fields in my qcubed project?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the QPanel control to add controls on the fly. Just set its AutoRenderChildren attribute to true and set the dynamic controls parent to the QPanel.

```
// Instantiate our QPanel - this will render a div to contain our dynamic controls
// Note that the parent is $this. You will need to call render in your template
$this->pnl = new QPanel($this);
// Setting AutoRenderChildren so that the Panel will handle Rendering our dynamic
// controls.
$this->pnl->AutoRenderChildren = true;
// Creating a button with an Ajax action to create our dynamic controls
$this->btn = new QButton($this);
$this->btn->Text = "Add Control";
$this->btn->AddAction(new QClickEvent(), new QAjaxAction('btn_Click'));

protected function btn_Click($strFormId, $strControlId, $strParameter) {
    // create the control and set its parent to the QPanel 
    $ctl = new QTextBox($this->pnl);        
}
```

You can get more information on using QPanels on the QCubed examples website.

[QCubed QPanel Example](http://examples.qcu.be/assets/_core/php/examples/multiple_qform/intro.php)